# Cannot write files to 2nd HDD

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I am having 2 HDD in my PC. The first one is a SDD which is for Ubuntu installation, and the second HDD is a drive to store other files.

I am able to access my second HDD but I cannot write or copy any files into it. The paste option is also blanked out. I clicked on its permission and saw that the HDD is owned by me.

I was using Windows 10 prior to this, if it helps.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating a file from command line (use `touch` for example)?

Comment: Error:  touch: cannot touch '123.txt': Read-only file system

Comment: If NTFS, you need fast start up off and no issues that need  chkdsk. Fast Start up off (always on hibernation), note that Windows turns this back on with updates, SHIFT + Shut down button http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

and then reboot my PC.

Somehow there was some windows error in it and the above command managed to fix it.